# Scope usage in ExtJS events and functions

Tags: events, extjs, scope

I am using ExtJS 4 for my Web application development. I need to fire [extjs](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs) [event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event) many time. Till now I did all stuffs without adding scope while firing event. It's working fine, but want to know what is purpose of third parameter which is scope and also it's optional. I am giving two snap-shots here. can Anyone help me to understand scope, the third parameter of [on](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-method-on) method? Thanks in advance. Sorry for my English.

```
 store.on('load',function(store, records, successful, eOpts){

         /**do some stuff here..*/
  });



store.on('load',function(store, records, successful, eOpts){

         /**do some stuff here..*/
  },[scope]); //scope added
```

Answer (score 3):

Look:

```
...
store.on({
    load: {
        fn: this.someFn,
        scope: window
    }
});

...

someFn: function(...) {
    console.log(this); // output: "Window /_display/" in FF
}
```

If you configure scope as `scope: store`, then "this" in someFn === store.

E.t.c.

With your code:

```
 store.on('load',function(store, records, successful, eOpts){

     console.log(this); // output: Object { your_component_instance }
 });



store.on('load',function(store, records, successful, eOpts){

     console.log(this); // output: Object { store_instance }
}, store); //scope added
```

Comment: Hi Vlad..thanks.. I got your your answer..but I am little bit confused that is it any performance issue in case I use scope = store or not?